# Creating a "Remind User" link in Views

Tags: 7, views, rules, emails

I've created a View that lists when a user has last logged in, using table format. I'm wanting to add a field that's a link to remind the user to login again (I've used a UID field and am rewriting the output to be a link, with UID as an argument at the end).

**What's the most sensible way to trigger an email via Views?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Views, I would use Rules + Rules Scheduler (bundled with Rules).  This will allow the site itself to automatically send e-mail reminders at intervals you specify.  Johan Falk explains how to set this up in his [Rules Scheduler screencasts](http://nodeone.se/sv/node/770).

EDIT: To do this in Views, I would add the Flag module, which also integrates with Rules.  Set up a flag for "Send reminder e-mail" (give permissions only to admin, etc.)  Then, write a rule that sends an e-mail that is triggered on the event "User is flagged..."  Last, add the flag as a relationship in your view and then add a flag link.

You will have to consider what to do about unflagging users.  By default, the user will show up as flagged after a reminder is sent, which might be nice because you'll know that the user has already received a reminder.  However, if you need something more sophisticated, you could make an additional rule that automatically unflags the user after he/she is flagged and keep track of the number of reminders you have sent by using flag's count property (also accessible via rules/views).

Comment: I'm already using Rules (and I expect this task will require it), but the goal isn't to set up scheduled emails -- the View shows when the user last logged in and when their most recent report on the site was generated. The idea is to let administrators send reminders to those who haven't logged in since their last report was created. Even if I had a scheduled rule set up, I'd still want this manual functionality. Thanks for the idea, though -- I might do that in the end if I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Ok, see my edit.

Comment: That seems a lot more sensible than what I'm doing. Will give it a shot and report back.